# How to copy multiple worksheets to another workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to copy data from multiple worksheets to another workbook using a loop.

The code breaks when it gets to

```
Set wsCopy = Workbooks("acex_resultsv1.xlsm").Worksheets(i)
```

```vb
Public Sub Update_Dashboard()

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long

Dim i As Integer

i = 1

Do While i <= Worksheets.Count
    Worksheets(i).Select

    Set wsCopy = Workbooks("acex_resultsv1.xlsm").Worksheets(i)
    Set wsDest = Workbooks("acex_results.xlsm").Worksheets(i + 1)

    lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

    wsDest.Range("A2:BI" & lDestLastRow).ClearContents

    wsCopy.Range("A2:BI" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
      wsDest.Range("A2")
  
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    i = i + 1
Loop
Worksheets("Dashboard").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: `Worksheets.Count` needs a specific workbook qualifier, unless all open workbooks have the same number of worksheets.  FYI when posting here it's useful to include the exact error message you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested:

```vb
Public Sub Update_Dashboard()

    Dim wbCopy As Workbook, wsCopy As Worksheet
    Dim wbDest As Workbook, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim lCopyLastRow As Long, lDestLastRow As Long, i As Long
    
    Set wbCopy = Workbooks("acex_resultsv1.xlsm")
    Set wbDest = Workbooks("acex_results.xlsm") 'ThisWorkbook?
    
    For i = 1 To wbCopy.Worksheets.Count
    
        Set wsCopy = wbCopy.Worksheets(i)
        Set wsDest = wbDest.Worksheets(i + 1)
    
        lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
        lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).row
        wsDest.Range("A2:BI" & lDestLastRow).ClearContents
        wsCopy.Range("A2:BI" & lCopyLastRow).Copy wsDest.Range("A2")
    
    Next i
     
    wbDest.Worksheets("Dashboard").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Tim.  Declare variables for source and destination workbooks, Worksheets.Count should be the count worksheets in wbSource.

Also note there is no reason to .Select anything in this process.  It only hogs memory.

Comment: Many thanks, this worked. Thanks for letting know to declare variables for source and destination workbooks.